# Is there a module that allows me to add files via ajax to a body field?

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax, javascript, files

I am using Drupal 7. I am looking for a module that allows users to drag and drop files (images/video/audio) inline into a body field with something like [jQuery UI sortable.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid) I would ideally like the user to be able to make a "media bank" in the node creation where they can upload their media and then drag and drop it where they want it in their post. Also, and I know that I am already asking a lot, it would be awesome if when the user added an image, they could resize it to the best fit for its position and placement in the body.

Do you have any suggestion, or anything close that I may be able to customize for my needs?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not exactly what you are looking for, but I'll mention them anyway, as it might give you further search directions:

- [plup](http://drupal.org/project/plup) module
- [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) module
- [Image Resize Filter](http://drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter) module

I like the plup module a lot, very easy to use, but based on image fields, not inline. Perhaps, in combination with the Insert module, you can get them inline. I don't like the resulting UI, as people won't understand why something so easy (putting an image inline, optionally with fixed dimensions) needs to be presented so complex.

The Media module is still thinking how to handle inline images; see the issue [#1283844](http://drupal.org/node/1283844).

Comment: +1 for introducing plub, also i'm agree with insert module for this case.